# Is any method to access BBM chat history from another app in android

Tags: android, chat, bb-messenger

I want to implement an app in android which accesses(read) BBM chat history from BBM chat app but not finding any solutions for this. 
Please suggest how to implement the same.
Thanks.!

Comment: Would seem like a pretty big security flaw if you could.

Comment: @Jamie Is it impossible.?

Comment: I don't know but I'd imagine if it was possible, RIM would fix it up quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BBM doesn't include any APIs to programmatically access chat history.

Comment: but there are couple of apps in market doing this by asking user to save chat history to phone.